# Prerequisites Dialog Appears When Running Setup.exe After Product Is Installed

Tags: installshield, prerequisites, installshield-2012

My question is as follows (I hope that someone will be able to help :) ):

I have an Installshield InstallScript Project with prerequisites.

Once the user tries to run the setup file, it shows the prerequisites dialog and the user is able to install the prerequisites - so far so good.

After the application is installed, the user decides to remove the prerequisite (.Net 4.5 in our case). He later wants to remove the application as well and launches the setup.exe again (he is **not** using the Add Remove Programs of Windows). When launching the setup file, the first dialog that appears is the prerequisites dialog.

Our setup supports only uninstallation if the application is already installed so there is no need for the prerequisites installation.

BTW, when uninstalling from the Add Remove Programs, the prerequisites dialog is not shown.

So, the question is: how can I disable the prerequisites dialog when launching the setup.exe on the second time?

Answer (score 2):

At the time of launch, the setup.exe doesn't know what you are going to do.

What you can do is edit the .net PRQ (or other PRQs) to have a condition that your app isn't installed, probably detecting your app via a registry key. However, multiple conditions on PRQs haven't always worked how I expected them too so YMMV.

Or you could just instruct your users to use add/remove programs. Simple is usually better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, editing the PRQ is not an option. I've also tried to re-educate the users but, alas, I've failed :(

Comment: I'd say you are pretty much out of options then.

Comment: the prq is just an xml file... of course you could edit it.  just don't tell whoever told you not to.  If @NGaida can keep a secret, you'll be golden.